# Jquery show & hide not working but native change to style.display does work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does toggling display between block/none work but jQuery show/hide does not?

Javascript:

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"
     onmouseover="document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';" 
     onmouseout="document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';">
   <div id="div1" style="display: none;">Text</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;" 
     onmouseover="$('#div1').show();" onmouseout="$('#div1').hide();">
   <div id="div1" style="display: none;">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The jQuery version seems to work here: http://jsbin.com/aruvun/1/

Comment: works fine for me. It has to be something else. What's the full page source?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using jquery and try to keep your CSS (design), html (markup) and javascript (interaction) always separated. You will avoid problems using frameworks like jQuery in the future.

The below code is an example of using mouseover in jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //starts after all html is loaded (after dom is loaded)
  $('#div1').hide();
  $("div.container").mouseover(function() {
    $('#div1').show();
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $('#div1').hide();
  });
});
```

Now use CSS for styling:

```
.container {
  width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;
}
```

As a result, your html can be semanticly correct:

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="div1">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree 100% that inline javascript should be avoided, especially when using a framework.  But I'm pretty sure the OP's code should work fine except for the invalid `src`.

Comment: I don't like inline JS but that isn't the problem. Jquery isn't looking for $('#div1') when the page loads, it's looking for it onmouseover which should be pretty obvious by the descriptive attribute name.

Comment: Well I guess it was the wrong part of my explanation since the attributes onmouseover and onmouseout only get triggered when the action happens.

Changed the explanation. It might be usefull for beginning scripters

Comment: I have to disagree with this still. You would not leave JS to hide that div, you would do that inline so the user is not seeing it while CSS and JS are loading.

Comment: @popnoodles - You could make the inline style set to `display:none` if that's a real concern.  But if your css loads before anything else and they still see an unstyled body, then there are other issues to address and using inline styles and scripting is a cop-out.

Comment: Well the best way is to hide it using CSS because the default behaviour is 'hide'. When you use jQuery the correct way, you will not be able to see a flicker or even the element before jQuery hides it. Common practish:

set vars -> set default states (hide/show etc) -> pre-proces stuff (calculations) -> animate or set interactions (click, hover etc) -> post-proces

Comment: What if that CSS didn't load first or at all? I would always put that inline.

Comment: " When you use jQuery the correct way, you will not be able to see a flicker" yes you will - it's not instant, jquery waits until the dom is ready and what if there's a lot of execution before it? It's too possible that user will see it flicker not to hide definitively right from the beginning with no room for error.

Comment: Unless you follow the coding practisch I explained above your comment, You will be able to get into those sorts of suprises.. But I do agree on the fact of using (external) CSS as default state setter.

Answer (score 0):

They both seem to work the same:

https://tinker.io/62ecc/1

If you are testing on a local file, the browser may be defaulting to the `file` scheme for the `src`.  Use a developer tool to confirm the response code for the script.

Comment: Omitting http: lets the browser decide whether to use http or https. It's totally valid. – Blender

Comment: speaking of omitting http, while it is ok to do so on the web, you shouldnt do it in emails because some older versions of outlook do not understand it

Comment: My browser assumes the scheme is `file` if I try //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js or //google.com.  And if I use the scheme, his code works as expected. So while the Tim Berners-Lee may say that it's valid, it is the most likely reason his code isn't working.

Comment: "My browser assumes the scheme is file" Only if you're looking at the HTML page as  `file://`

Comment: i made a mistake in the url when cop/pasting from google cdn ... http in jquery source is missing. google should put that. and it will save us a lot time for a small slip.

Comment: @popnoodles - were you running the script locally?  Based on your comment, I updated my tinker : https://tinker.io/62ecc/1 to match your code and it works fine.

Comment: Yes I was but not as `file://`, as `http://localhost` because as you now know as `file://` the browser thinks that's the protocol.

Comment: @popnoodles - I just ran it from my desktop, didn't work, network tool showed the url as `file://`, then ran from my local web root directory (`http://localhost/test.html`)  and it worked. So I'll admit I learned  something new about URLs but I still think the OP's issue is that they ran it from local filesystem instead of from http server.

Answer (score 0):

if parent div is the first div in your code then u can either use `$('div:first')` or can give id to parent like..

```
<script>
    $(function(){
     $('#div1').hide();
     $('div#Parent').hover(function(){
     $('#div1').toggle();
     });
    });
</script>


<div id="Parent" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">
   <div id="div1">Text</div>
</div>
```

using `hover()` and `toggle()` make your code concise which are equivalent to events that you need.

Comment: well i did'nt know that same/any answer has given or not as the time i was writing i switch the tab to do other important work.

Comment: i have edit the post and now its working for after page load also.

Comment: ooh i appolozise for not removing the `display:none` attribute from div1. i edit that now.

Comment: well its working here [link](http://jsbin.com/ibatuw/1/edit). Hover() binds handlers for both mouseover() and mouseleave(). if one hover() can accomplish the required task then i guess it makes sense to use it.